# How do you get your sprite to bounce of the screen edges on your screen?

Tags: java, velocity, 2d-games

I have a tester program which is used to build the start of a game.

I am having issues with the velocity attributes in the if statements which are supposed to create the bounce effect off the sprite of the screen but I can't seem to get the correct combination. Been working on this for a good while and cant seem to get any progress. Any help will be appreciated.

On a side note, in the else if methods there is a attribute called getWidth and getHeight, this is supposed to get the height and width of the screen. But I am unsure if it does. I can attach that class if needed. But below I will add the method I have for trying to create this "Bounce" effect of the edges of my screen.

```
public void checkScreenEdge(Sprite s){
    if (s.getX() > getWidth()){

    }
    else if (s.getX() + s.getWidth() >= getWidth());
    {

    }

    if (s.getY() > getHeight()) {

    }
    else if (s.getY() + s.getHeight() >= getHeight())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `x < 0 || x + width > width` be more appropriate?  Then you could just modify the velocity in the opposite direction `xVelocity *= -1`?

Comment: Hope you are calling you method at some predefined rate per second.

Comment: @Abhijith: but it's always best to calculate real time slices

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a deltaX and deltaY value (or velocity value) to decide which direction to move, simply change the value from positive to negative or visa versa at the appropriate location. For example:

```
if (s.getX() <= 0) {
   s.setDeltaX(Math.abs(s.getDeltaX());
} else if (s.getX() + s.getWidth() >= MAX) {
   s.setDeltaX(-Math.abs(s.getDeltaX());
}
```

I feel that it's important to use absolute value rather than directly swapping deltaX values, because if you did this:

```
if (s.getX() <= 0) {
    s.setDeltaX(-s.getDeltaX());
}
```

you risk the sprite being "trapped" at the edges with the deltas being flipped repeatedly due to an over-shoot.

Comment: When you say > = Max, What do you mean by this? The max of what value?

Comment: @CaptainCode: that's for you to decide and define -- the right border of your model.

Comment: Could you not just assign that to be the size of the screen? I have a class which automatically contains the size of the screen, so I could use this right? Or would I need to create a new variable

Comment: @CaptainCode: if that's your need, you could, but often this sort of decision is made in the model code, not the view code as the latter's function is only to visualize the state of the model.